Meu EOF não funciona como esperado, alguém tem alguma sugestão de como ajeitar isso?
Bom, estou tentando usar EOF em código e ele meio que buga, procurei o porque é pelo que parece é porque estou utilizando variáveis que excedem o valor de um LONG_MAX e queria saber como posso resolver isso.
Se quiserem me passar alguma dica de como melhorar o código também.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

//verifica se o número é primo
int ehprimo(long long int p){
    //long int raiz = sqrt(p);
    long long int d;
    for(d = 2;d <= sqrt(p);d++){
        if (p%d==0)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}


long long int acharPrimoAnt(long long int num,long long int i){
    //se o número for primo, e maior que um retorna ele mesmo menos 1. EX: 9  
    if(ehprimo(num)==1 && i-num!=1 && num >1){
        //printf("%lli\n",num);
        return num-1+acharPrimoAnt(i-num, i-num);    
    //se for não for primo eu passo para o número anterior. EX : 9-1, 9
    }else if (num > 1)
        return acharPrimoAnt(num-1, i);
    else
        return 0;
}

int main() {
    long long int N;
    while(scanf("%lld",&N)!=EOF){
        if(N%2 == 0 && N != 2)
            printf("%lld\n",N-2);
        else
            printf("%lld\n",acharPrimoAnt(N,N));
            //printf("r = %li\n",acharPrimoAnt(N,N));
    }
    return 0;
}


A conversa se estendeu e foi movida para um chat;

Importante você [edit] sua pergunta convertendo o código em um [mcve] de um problema específico, explicar como tentou resolver e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.

Sugestao para nao utilizar <math.h> e evitar outros possiveis problemas com valores de virgula flutuante, alem de ser mais eficiente!
// nao vamos testar se -17 eh primo, por isso "unsigned"
int ehprimo(long long unsigned p) {
    if (p < 2) return 0;            // nem 0 nem 1 sao primos
    if (p == 2) return 1;           // dois eh primo
    if (p % 2 == 0) return 0;       // 4, 6, 8, 10, ... nao sao primos
                                    // ciclo testa 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, ...
    for (long long unsigned d = 3; d <= p / d; d += 2) {
        if (p % d == 0) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

